# Fan speed controller and fried PSU

Tags: power-supply, fan

My PC came with a manual fan speed controller (FSC) for the front and back case fan. The FSC was connected to a 3-pin case fan header on the motherboard and then connected to a 1-to-2 fan splitter where the connectors for the two fans were plugged in.

At some point it became mechanically faulty and I replaced it with a very cheap manual FSC (Gelid FC-MC01-B), which worked fine for some months. Then a week ago the PC suddenly shut off and wouldn't turn on anymore. I noticed a charred smell coming from the PSU. So now I've replaced the PSU and everything works fine, except the FSC: The case fans do not rotate at all.

If I plug the fans directly to the motherboard connector, they work (though obviously they run at maximum speed and are very noisy).

**So before I again buy a new fan speed controller, is there anything to consider?** Can a bad FSC cause the PSU to fry (okay, the PSU was 4+ years old)? Or did the PSU, when it fried, damage the FSC (which is a bit weird because it left anything else undamaged)?

Answer (score 1):

The PSU killed your FSC (or both went wrong same time).

FSC cannot kill a standard PSU. Every PSU have short-circuit protection,
the only thing what the FSC can produce for the PSU.

Comment: so I guess that I'm just super-lucky that from all the hardware the PSU killed it was only the FSC? How could that be?

Comment: Simply: Every PC hardware have its own protection, protect their critical parts. Your FSC is cheap, because it have minimal or none protection related to overvoltage, overcurrent etc. Not super-lucky, but lucky :)